# calling a function several times with saving result

Tags: javascript, function, function-call

I've got a question.

I need to design a function `add()` which would sum up given arguments. The problem is that it should be able to be called in several ways as follows:

```
add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) // outputs 15
add(1, 2)(3)(4, 5) // outputs 15
add(1, 2, 3)(4, 5) // outputs 15
```

if the inner part of the function is not a problem and can be implemented like:

```
return arg.reduce((prev, current) => prev + current)
```

The number of arguments is always 5. No more, no less.

However, I am not sure how to deal with consecutive calls here. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not possible without `valueOf` coercion or knowing the number of times it'll be called in advance, I think

Comment: You could possible curry the function, or use higher-order functions (also called first class functions - essentially a function that returns a function)

Comment: actually yes, sorry for omitting that, the number of arguments is always 5. No more, no less.

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53129691/edit) and then click the snippet editor `[<>]` to provide use a [mcve] - it is not clear how you call this and why it is a problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have `add` return a function that has a persistent array in its scope, that keeps track of all arguments that have been passed in, cumulatively. On each call, `push` to that array - once that array has 5 items, return the summed array as a number, otherwise, return the same function:

```js
function add(...initialArgs) {
  const allArgs = [];
  function inner(...args) {
    allArgs.push(...args);
    return allArgs.length === 5
     ? allArgs.reduce((a, b) => a + b)
     : inner;
  }
  return inner(...initialArgs)
}

console.log(add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) // outputs 15
console.log(add(1, 2)(3)(4, 5)) // outputs 15
console.log(add(1, 2, 3)(4, 5)) // outputs 15
```

Of course, this depends on knowing in advance that the total number of arguments will always be exactly 5.

Answer (score 0):

This one is sort of generic approach in which you can pass dynamic arguments to "add" function below and it will be taken care by "parseAdd" function.

In general this problem falls under the category of "currying" function, which is worth reading. Also, understanding of [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) and [function.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString) will help you understand this approach better.

```js
function addition(...args) {
  return args.reduce((conc, v) => conc += v ,0)
}
                
            
function parseAdd(fn) {
  var newFn = fn.bind(null);

  function cal(...args) {
    newFn = newFn.bind(null, ...args);
    return cal;
  }

  cal.toString = () => newFn();

  return (...arg) => { newFn = fn.bind(null); return cal(...arg) }
}
                
           
var add = parseAdd(addition);

console.log(add(1,2,3,4))
console.log(add(1,2,3)(4)(5))
console.log(add(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6))
```